# Controling the GUI with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am writing this C++ application with wxWidgets.

I want to reproduce the following situation:

- There must be one single mainFrame which should control the others.
- Other windows should appear inside this mainFrame (like sections)
- wxNotebook must not be used.

Imagine I have wxFrameMain, wxPanelA, and wxPanelB. The application should start wxFrameMain filled up with wxPanelA and after the user choses to change the view, it should get filled up with wxPanelB.

Does anyone have any tutorial or can explain how to do that?

Comment: You can always check very helpful [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/). It can generate c++ code from Your design.

Comment: I am using codeblocks. The problem is about switching between the pages.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. wxFormBuilder will generate code for You, which You can use in codeblocks, or wherever it will be needed.

Comment: I know. My problem is not generating the code. It's about controlling the views' flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to understand what does the requirement

> wxNotebook must not be used

actually mean. Does this mean that the user shouldn't be able to change the pages on his own? If so, you are probably looking for [wxSimplebook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_simplebook.html). If it just means that the user should be able to change pages but using UI different from `wxNotebook`, then perhaps one of the other [book controls](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_bookctrl.html) can be helpful.

Comment: I want to switch btween views inside th same frame, but without using a tab like GUI.

Comment: It would be like a bookControl that isnt bound to any other control such as list or tabs. So I can control which page will be shown from the backend code. Will this simpleBook fit in this situation?

Comment: Yes, `wxSimplebook` is a book control without the UI.